# Write frames to kinesis video stream using java

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I am using aws lambda for processing the frame, which generates png image sequences as output. i want to push these processed frames to amzaon kinesis-video-stream. how to do it in java?

Answer (score 3):

I found the way, we can not directly push png or jpg format to kvs,as kinesis video stream takes only h264 format video fragments, so first we need to convert the list of images into video(you can use ffmpeg to convert from image to video) and then send the same mkv video file using putmedia api to kinesis video stream.
you can see the [example here in java](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-java/blob/master/src/main/demo/com/amazonaws/kinesisvideo/demoapp/PutMediaDemo.java).

Answer (score 0):

On your lambda screen left side of you and right side of the screen you can find KVS kinesis video stream, I know only this much